# Jest/Enzyme ReactNative how can I test the state in a functional component

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a functional component which use `useState` in it. How can I test its state through jest?

I tried:

```
test('Test state', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>)
      console.log(wrapper.state())
```

I receive this error:

```
ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on class components
```

Comment: you don't really need that. just call some prop on nested components and verify what has been changed in rendering result. this way you actually test how component behaves as it was inside some application